# How to filter a large dataset - python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter months of January, February and December from a dataset and the output only shows the header as the result how can I resolve this in python?

```py
df_w = df[(df['month'] < 3) & (df['month'] > 11) ]
df_w
```

Comment: You need to use `|` operation instead of '&'. For sure the month cannot be 'January' and 'December' at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Use `|` operation instead of `&`

```
df_w = df[(df['month'] < 3) | (df['month'] > 11) ]
df_w
```